# Spring boot - cannot use @Value annotation

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to use the `@Value` to load some value from application.properties based on the profile, but there is something that does not work...

In my application.properties I have

```
spring.datasource.url=@jdbc.url@
```

I have

```
<resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

in my pom.xml. When compiling, i see that my application.properties has the right value of jdbc.url

Then i want to use this property when connecting to the DB

```
 @Value("${jdbc.url}") 
    private String dbUrl;

        @PostConstruct
        public Connection getConnection(){

                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                return DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, "user", "xxxxxxx");
            }
```

but dbUrl is null...
Do i need something else?

Comment: Read your code again (small hint `spring.datasource.url` != `jdbc.url`)..... Also I would say what you are doing (first using maven to replace variables) is wrong to begin with...

Comment: thanks.. what an error... but why using maven with profiles to set properties is wrong?

Comment: Why are you constructing the `Connection` manually anyway? Doing this sort of thing automatically is the whole point of using Boot.

Comment: Why it is wrong, because it means you are creating artifacts per environment whereas you should be using Spring Profiles and only build a single artifact. When building artifacts per environment (dev, test, prod) you are basically going live with an untested artifact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should load the value like this:

```
@Value("${spring.datasource.url}") 
private String dbUrl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need specify delimiters, inside your plugins.

```
 <configuration>
    <delimiters>
        <delimiter>@</delimiter>
    </delimiters>
    <useDefaultDelimiters>false</useDefaultDelimiters>
</configuration>
```